# The finiteness of a monotonic function's limit

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Suppose that $f:(a,\infty) \to \mathbb R$ is a monotonic differentiable (or even smooth, if necessary) function such that $\lim_\infty f'\to 0$.
These conditions are not sufficient to guarantee that $f$ has a finite limit, as demonstrated by $f(x) = \log x$, in which case $f'(x) = 1/x$, so that $f'> 0$ and $f'\to 0$, but $f\to\infty$.

I am interested in finding further conditions which would assure that $f$ has a finite limit  at $\infty$. Of course, one such condition would be that $f$ is bounded (and then the condition $f'\to 0$ is superfluous) but this is too strong. In particular, is there such a condition that depends only on the derivative $f'$ rather than $f$ itself?

I am aware of [Barbalat's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_stability#Barbalat%27s_lemma_and_stability_of_time-varying_systems) but its original version seems to work the other way around (i.e. it concludes that $f'\to 0$ rather than assuming it). The alternative version presented on Wikipedia also does not seem to be useful unless we expect that $f \to 0$ (otherwise, the only way I can think of utilizing it is to consider the difference between $f$ and the expected limit, but that presupposes the knowledge of the limit which seems like a non-trivial thing in general).

Comment: One (trivial but natural) condition is that $f'(x)$ is integrable on say $[a+1,\infty)$, by the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: @GregMartin Thanks! In view of this, it would also suffice that $x^\alpha f'(x) \to 0$ for some $\alpha > 1$, which is something that I might actually be able to utilize.

Comment: Maybe this condition (although I'm not certain it's correct and so it probably requires tweaking): There does not exist $k \geq 0\ $ such that $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to \infty} \vert f''(x)\vert \leq \frac{k}{x^2}$ ? But basically my idea is to have some condition on $f''(x)$ in terms of $x$ or maybe in terms of $f'(x)$ also.

Comment: While sufficiently unrelated to the OP, but it's a lovely problem to show that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ existing and $\lim_{x\to\infty} f''(x)=0$ do together imply $\lim_{x\to\infty} f'(x)=0$.

Comment: @GregMartin Perhaps a future analysis exam question ;)

Comment: It's lovely in a Putnam-y way (indeed, "$f\to0$ and $f'''\to0 \implies f'\to0$ and $f''\to0$" was literally a Putnam question), but perhaps a bit too lateral-thinking to be a good instrument of assessment :)